# Shiny - Changing Variables on a Graph Based on User Input

Tags: variables, shiny, interactive, linegraph

I would like the user to be able to select which variable is on the x-axis of a graph. My data frame looks like this:

```
> linegraphdata
   Year   E_coli Rain_Intensity Water_Temperature Dew_Point  Humidity Wind_Speed Barometric_Pressure Visibility Cloud_Cover
1  2006 181.4173    0.004077910          79.51720  60.08460 0.6747836   8.092537            1015.748   9.108940   0.5146045
2  2007 212.3498    0.005503364          80.36213  60.06608 0.6597432   6.074101            1015.417   9.173431   0.5019472
3  2008 127.0755    0.003195506          77.77268  58.15240 0.6559700   7.855993            1014.482   9.590509   0.5037079
4  2009 151.2129    0.004728056          74.56725  55.57986 0.6704676   6.278484            1014.511   9.389780   0.5461991
5  2010 142.9604    0.005628907          80.73180  61.37344 0.6662863   6.263983            1014.919   9.536397   0.4672130
6  2011 121.5559    0.005370608          79.44271  60.18298 0.6682699   6.879726            1013.199   9.467782   0.4891249
7  2012 126.4385    0.002568511          80.99142  57.04450 0.5765744   7.416897            1014.416   9.767905   0.3841238
8  2013 142.2380    0.004249872          76.72413  58.13510 0.6703193   7.058155            1015.610   9.451731   0.4211622
9  2014 139.4780    0.006628609          74.93213  58.53608 0.7117897   6.342423            1014.847   9.318628   0.3082917
10 2015 127.3011    0.004109462          75.38712  58.15503 0.7069821   7.058145            1014.534   9.378120   0.3086044
11 2016 123.7218    0.003886790          80.46863  63.90303 0.7176918   6.508438            1014.887   9.648991   0.2763920
```

The problem is, Shiny is taking the input$predictor at face value, and just graphing the variable name instead of the list of values attached to that variable name. It is not recognizing that the selected variable name is associated with a data frame containing values.

Note: I *want* the first graph to be static. I only want the second graph to change.

This is what the app looks like when it's running:
[Static image of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87sNj.png)

Here is my app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

linegraphdata = read.csv("linegraphdata.csv")

predictor_options <-
  c(
    "Rain_Intensity",
    "Water_Temperature",
    "Dew_Point",
    "Humidity",
    "Wind_Speed",
    "Barometric_Pressure",
    "Visibility",
    "Cloud_Cover"
  )

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(12, offset = 0, tags$h1("Pick a Predictor:")),
  column(
    12,
    offset = 0,
    tags$h4(
      "Which elements of the environment trend with ",
      tags$i("E. coli"),
      " levels? Look for
      the predictor whose line graph peaks and valleys with the average",
      tags$i("E. coli"),
      "levels. "
    )
  ),
  column(4, offset = 0,
         ########################## HERE IS RELEVANT CODE:
         wellPanel(
           selectInput("predictor", "Select a Predictor", choices = predictor_options)
         )),
  column(10,
         plotOutput("graph3"))
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$predictor, {
    plot1 <-
      ggplot(data = linegraphdata, aes(x = Year, y = E_coli)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
    ########################## HERE IS RELEVANT CODE:
    plot2 <-
      ggplot(data = linegraphdata, aes(x = Year, y = input$predictor)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
    output$graph3 <- renderPlot({
      grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 1)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! I just needed to add some lines that tie the input back to the data frame (on the server side). I stored the input in a reactive() function and got rid of the observeEvent() function.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
if ( "Rain_Intensity" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Rain_Intensity)
if ( "Water_Temperature" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Water_Temperature)
if ( "Dew_Point" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Dew_Point)
if ( "Humidity" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Humidity)
if ( "Wind_Speed" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Wind_Speed)
if ( "Barometric_Pressure" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Barometric_Pressure)
if ( "Visibility" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Visibility)
if ( "Cloud_Cover" %in% input$predictor) return(linegraphdata$Cloud_Cover)

  })
plot1 <- ggplot(data= linegraphdata, aes(x=Year, y=E_coli)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
plot2 <- ggplot(data = linegraphdata, aes(x=Year, y=data())) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
output$graph3 <- renderPlot({grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=1)})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `input$predictor` values **exactly** match the column names of your `linegraphdata` data.frame you can also use `aes_string` from ggplot (to use strings or quoted names/calls to define the aesthetic mappings):

```
plot2 <- ggplot(data = linegraphdata, aes_string(x = "Year", y = input$predictor)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

That way you do not need a reactive function with multiple `if` statements.

Comment: When I run this, I get the following error:

    Warning: Error in aes_string: object 'Year' not found
    Stack trace (innermost first):
        46: aes_string
        45: inherits
        44: ggplot.data.frame
        43: ggplot
        42: server [C:/Users/Renel/Documents/Fake         Desktop/App/sampleapp.R#49]
         1: runApp
    Error in aes_string(x = Year, y = datainput$predictor) : 
      object 'Year' not found

Comment: You need quotes around Year as in "Year" - do you have that?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you! However, you do still need the reactive function.